# Redirecting old permalink structure to the new one

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I had a wordpress site installed in a sub folder with category/post-title permalink structure, which resulted in the following url structure

**http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/category/post-title**

However as I needed to move my site to the root folder and changed the permalink structure to year/month/post-title, which looks like below, users who visit my website through the links published on other websites see 404 error page as expected.

**http://www.mysite.com/year/month/post-title**

While doing the changes, moving wordpress to the root directory and changing permalink structure, I forgot to take into account that such problem could occur. Anyway, I made a mistake and now I'm trying to fix the problem.

I wonder is there a way to redirect the old urls to the new ones? Editing .htaccess or using a plugin or something else. The method doesn't matter at this stage. All I want is to solve the problem

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [WordPress › Redirection « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/), which will 301 redirect, import a csv of redirects and log 404s without having to deal with mod_rewrite and .htaccess.

Comment: Hey @songdogtech, I've tried to make use of the plugin but apparently the plugin is broken. I can create neither redirection nor any module. I wrote about the problem in the plugin discussion forums. Hope it'll be fixed soon. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't know of any bugs. In my experience, that plugin works flawlessly.

Comment: Hey @songdogtech, I've resolved the problem with the plugin. The plugin was not creating redirection tables in the database. So I had to Delete Redirection under Options section of the plugin and then reactivate it. Now the plugin as well as redirections works flawlessly. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is what you're looking for, if you have that kind of access to your server.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Do I need to write a redirect/rewrite rule for each post or is there a way to address all the posts?

Comment: The link explains it all - you get to match an expression to the requested URL, so assuming all your post-titles are the same, you can just match the first part `/subfolder/category/` and replace it with `/year/month/`

If your post titles are different, you'll have a more difficult time, as renaming all of those isn't trivial.

Comment: As an example: A simple entry would look something like this (for an old post www.mysite.com/subfolder/category/post-title and the corresopnding new post www.mysite.com/year/month/post-title)
 `RewriteRule ^subfolder/category/(.*)$ /year/month/$1`
But, that's just off the top of my head (can't remember the finer points of the regex engine). Someone more familiar with the regexes and Apache may have a better explanation, or you may just dive into the documentation and get your specific case figured out.

Comment: Hey @uscere90, I've tried quite many rewriterules based on your example and mod_rewrite documentation but have not been able to solve the problem unfortunately =( Btw, there is one thing I forgot to mention. I didn't just move my site to the root directory on the same server. I moved the site to another server and set redirection rules from domain panel and redirected the domain to the site installed on the root directory of new server. Do you think that this has anything to do with the problem? Regards.

Comment: Perhaps? If I understand you correctly, you set up a redirection using the domain panel of your old site? And this points to the new site?  If this is the case, your rewrite rules may have to be slightly different, as the request that your old server redirects to your new server might be somewhat different from a user trying to access www.mysite.com/subfolder/category/post-title directly from your new site.  The plugin songdog mentioned should do all this without any hassle. I'd recommend taking another look at it.  What kind of problems/errors are you getting?

Comment: Hey! I've opted to go for Redirection plugin. There was a small problem with the plugin but I fixed the and added all the redirections. All works smooth now. Thanks for the help... As a side note, I've found some tutorials on apache mod_rewrite. I'll learn more about it and then do all the redirections without plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) should be the way to go. If you're using IIS, you'll need different solutions based upon whether you're on IIS 6.x or IIS 7.x.

Comment: yeah, i'm using apache. but do I need to write a redirect/rewrite rule for each post or is there a way to address all the posts?

Comment: Looks like unscere90 hit on some rewrite details below. In short, you should be able to match posts with regex's and the mod_rewrite syntax.

Comment: As a caveat, be careful about conflicts between the rules that Wordpress writes out and any custom rules you add. I recall chasing my tail for the better part of an evening trying to overcome conflicts between these rules.

Comment: while trying various rewriterules based on @uscere90's sample code, I encountered some conflicts already =)